# Why does i got lifetime error in rust closure

Tags: rust, rust-wasm

I'm testing some rust wasm features, and have some problem with closures.
I'm implemented this function, which setup callback on button click event.

```
pub fn setup_click(&mut self) {
    let mut clicks = 0;
    let ws_cloned = self.websocket.clone();
    let num_clicks_cloned = self.num_clicks.clone();
    let notifications = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Notificator::new(
        NotificationConfig::new_default(),
    )));
    let cb = move |_: Event| {
        clicks += 1;
        num_clicks_cloned
            .borrow_mut()
            .set_inner_html(clicks.to_string());
        let mut map: Map<String, Value> = serde_json::Map::new();
        map.insert("key".to_string(), Value::String(clicks.to_string()));
        if let Ok(ws) = ws_cloned.clone().try_borrow_mut() {
            ws.send_rpc(
                String::from("click"),
                Params::Map(map),
                Box::new(|payload: String| {
                    notifications.clone().borrow_mut().display(
                        payload,
                        "Click success".to_string(),
                        "success".to_string(),
                    )
                }),
            );
        }
    };
    self.click_button.add_event_listener("click", cb);
}
```

where third param of the ws.send rpc is

```
pub type RPCHandler = Box<dyn Fn(String) + 'static>;
```

and add_event_listener has this sugnature

```
pub fn add_event_listener<T>(&mut self, event_name: &str, handler: T)
where
    T: 'static + FnMut(web_sys::Event),
{
    let cb = Closure::wrap(Box::new(handler) as Box<dyn FnMut(_)>);
    if let Some(el) = self.el.take() {
        let el_et: EventTarget = el.into();
        el_et
            .add_event_listener_with_callback(event_name, cb.as_ref().unchecked_ref())
            .unwrap();
        cb.forget();
        if let Ok(el) = el_et.dyn_into::<web_sys::Element>() {
            self.el = Some(el);
        }
    }
}
```

When i try to compile the code i got life time error

````
  --> src/test_click_btn.rs:46:21
   |
35 |           let cb = move |_: Event| {
   |                    --------------- lifetime `'1` represents this closure's body
...
46 | /                     Box::new(|payload: String| {
47 | |                         notifications.clone().borrow_mut().display(
48 | |                             payload,
49 | |                             "Click success".to_string(),
50 | |                             "success".to_string(),
51 | |                         )
52 | |                     }),
   | |______________________^ cast requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
   |
   = note: closure implements `FnMut`, so references to captured variables can't escape the closure```

I see that notifications not live long enough, but can't understand how to fix this error)
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no guarantee *in this code* that the closure passed to `send_rpc` will last no longer than the event callback closure. Therefore, it needs to be made [a `move` closure](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.move.html) too, so that it can live independently rather than borrowing from the event handler closure.

Conveniently, you already have `notifications` wrapped in `Rc`, which is just what you need, but you've performed the clone in the wrong place. This line

```rust
notifications.clone().borrow_mut().display(
```

performs a clone and dereferences it immediately, so it's redundant. Instead, you need to clone it *before creating the closure* so that the closure (now `move`) can own it:

```rust
    let notifications = notifications.clone();  // create a clone that will be moved into the closure
    ws.send_rpc(
        String::from("click"),
        Params::Map(map),
        Box::new(move |payload: String| {       // now a move closure
            notifications.borrow_mut().display( // no clone here
                ...
```